JUnit 5 - Migration - Custom test annotation no longer detected?
I had the following custom test annotation that worked in JUnit4 that IntelliJ and JUnit no longer wants to recognize:
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface MyTest{}

If I add @Test to the annotation then IntelliJ recognizes it again

but JUnit still don't and returns "No tests were found" when trying to run it.
The only change I've made to the pom is exchanged the dependency spring-test (version 4.3.25.RELEASE) for spring-boot-starter-test (version 2.7.18). I can't find anything in the documentation that indicates that this shouldn't work so I'm at a lost why it's broken

Try to annotate it with @Testable.

@MuratKaragöz No sadly, same thing. IntelliJ finds the test but JUnit don't recognize it

What do you mean by IntelliJ "finds the test"?

That I get the run option arrow, I've added an image of it to the OP for clarity

Yeah.. that is IntelliJ being smart. Do you have the right dependencies for jupiter? Have a look here https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#migrating-from-junit4

Indeed I do, I've migrated everything else already and tested that it works. It's just this this one custom annotation that stopped working.

Apparently there was something strange with my generated target files. After deleting them manually and running build pipeline again afterwards it now recognizes the tests again.
